# Как сделать выпадающий блок dropdown поверх другого блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dropdown

Есть выпадающий блок div, который при нажатии на button выпадает, но отодвигает вниз нижний контент. Как сделать, чтобы он не отодвигал, а выпадал поверх контента?

```
<button>меню</button>
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>Контакты</li>
    <li>Личный кабинет</li>
    <li>Сообщения</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">Контент</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");

button.onclick = function () {
  if (menu.className === "open") {
    menu.className = "";
  } else {
    menu.className = "open"
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative
}
.dropdown ul {
  display: none
}
.dropdown ul.open {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<button id="button">меню</button>
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>Контакты</li>
    <li>Личный кабинет</li>
    <li>Сообщения</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Контент</p>
  <p>Контент</p>
  <p>Контент</p>
  <p>Контент</p>
</div>
```

Comment: почему не использовать метод toggle? И если у меня у ul#menu будет класс ? что произойдет ?

Comment: @NeedHate суть вопроса была не в этом, поэтому привел минимальный пример. Можно и toggle, если используется jQuery. По моему примеру, конечно, класс будет заменен

Comment: чистый js тоже позволяет переключать класс.

Comment: @NeedHate можно использовать методы `classList`. Давненько поддержку не проверял по нему, сейчас, в принципе, можно смело применять.